# Vue fade in a list of images one at a time on load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, settimeout, vue-transitions

I have a project in Vue where I need to show images. These images are contained inside a. When the page is loaded I want the images to fade in one at a time. I have added a transition group with a fade in effect and added a function where each image gets added with a small delay.

I don't seem to get the images to show up after each others. The images show up all at once.

I have tried to put my code into the snipper below. But I don't seem to get the href source to get bounded. In my project i use local images stored in the `assets/img` folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <transition-group name="fade">
    <div v-for="logo in logos" :key="logo.id">
      <img :src="logo.filename" alt="">
    </div>
  </transition-group>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '',
      data() {
        return {
          logos: []
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        const addedLogos = [{
            id: 1,
            filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
          },
        ]
        addedLogos.forEach(logo => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            const newLogos = this.logos
            newLogos.push(logo)
            this.logos = newLogos
          }, 100)
        })
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style scoped>
    .fade-enter-active,
    .fade-leave-active {
      transition: opacity .5s;
    }
    
    .fade-enter,
    .fade-leave-to {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the `setTimeout` calls happen immediately.  They don't delay the loop and cause the next iteration to wait, so each image is scheduled to show at the same time.

You could use the `forEach` loop index to schedule them incrementally:

```js
addedLogos.forEach((logo, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const newLogos = this.logos
    newLogos.push(logo)
    this.logos = newLogos
  }, 100 * (index + 1))
})
```

Here's a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      logos: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const addedLogos = [{
      id: 1,
      filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
    },{
      id: 2,
      filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
    },{
      id: 3,
      filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
    },{
      id: 4,
      filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
    },{
      id: 5,
      filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
    },{
      id: 6,
      filename: 'http://files.gamebanana.com/img/ico/sprays/4f68c8d10306a.png'
    }]

    addedLogos.forEach((logo, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const newLogos = this.logos
        newLogos.push(logo)
        this.logos = newLogos
      }, 100 * (index + 1))
    })
    
  }
})
```

```css
div div, div div img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="fade">
    <div v-for="logo in logos" :key="logo.id">
      <img :src="logo.filename" alt="">
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```